# What is "View v" in the typical "onClick" call in Java?

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

In the generated code below, `v` is never referred to. What exactly does it represent in terms of the clicking and listening and subsequent action that occurs?

```
btnReturnToUI.setOnClickListener
       (new OnClickListener() 
       {
           public void onClick(View v) ///////////////////////////// 
           {
               MainActivity currentActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
               currentActivity.showUI();
           }
       }
);
```

Comment: The widget which has been clicked. `btnReturnToUI` in this case,

Comment: That is an unrecpectful answer. We have to help every body, not only experts.

Comment: We've to help everyone, but at least someone who shows (s)he made the effort to read *at least* the official doc, [which](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View)) states: "View: The view that was clicked". Which part is not clear of that sentence?

Comment: @Alessio--This got 4 upvotes. Why do you judge differently? Why judge? It's 2.4 years old. What were you looking for? Look at the majority of questions from 5 years ago. Many show no research effort yet were upvoted hundreds of times and answered gleefully with only rare criticism. The mood of SO has changed to the point that *it doesn't seem safe to ask ANY question now,* with so many people sniping at any Question they can. My rep of 1802 today was far from that 2.4 years ago. I surely don't recall searching for documentation. What if I did and couldn't find any? Where do I go for help?\

Comment: @Alessio, the explanation of "View: The view that was clicked" is not very informative and it's pretty reasonable to ask for a more thorough explanation. I'd like one as well

Comment: @rfii the context is [View.onClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener), which states: "Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked". So you're clicking a view, and you invoke a callback. I assume you know what a view is, and what a callback is. Now you've "View: The view that was clicked". Is there any part that is not clear to you in this sentence and in this context?
I accept that is reasonable to ask for help, but I also think everyone on SO should make an effort first.

Comment: @alessio, I think our perspective differs in that I don't have a good grip on what a view or callback is, contrary to your assumption. Given the core premise of the question, I doubt the question asker knows either. I am reading this thread to precisely to better understand what a view is and the specific ways it is used. I've taken two reputable college computer programming courses and never encountered a callback, but I have spent a few hours reading about them, which was quite confusing because much documentation and explanatory websites explain them using other terms I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Continuing... I think this website should be open to questions from beginners with 1 or 2 courses like me. I also know some people can be extremely dense, but my level of understanding was comparable to my peers so I doubt my interest in this question is abnormal for someone of my level.  Hope this changes your perspective on these sorts of questions and I thank you for your further explanation of what the view.onclicklistener is.  I hadn't thought about it as a callback before.  Again, thanks!

Comment: @rfii here you can find the definition of a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), and here one of a [view](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui). Basically view is anything you can view on screen, any part of the UI. And you want to have a way to execute code when any view is clicked, to do something with it. So the 'call' will be 'back' to you, so that you can control the execution flow. For instance you click a button, and pop up a dialog or show a message or go somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the thing you've clicked / set the listener on. In your example it's the same as `btnReturnToUI`.

One of the uses for this is to register the same listener on multiple buttons and then do different things in the listener depending on `v` or `v.getId()` which is the id in the xml layout e.g. `@+id/the_id`

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is in Android context. `v` is the view that was clicked (it could be a `Button`, a `TextView`, etc.). See the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) for a description:

> *`v`*  The view that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

It is the view that was clicked. That parameter is there so that you can assign a single OnClickListener to many views and still find out which view was clicked.

You can separate them from an ID or even the type of View so that you can perform different actions depending on the type or ID of the clicked item.